# Lua array not detecting closing bracket '}'

Tags: arrays, lua

My Lua script fails with the error

> '}' expected near 'OF'

at the line where I declare a large array.

I used to have it split across multiple line like so:

```
local array = {lots,
               of,
               array,
               elements}
```

but even after I put it in one line like so:

```
local array = {lots, of, array, elements}
```

I'm still getting the same error.
I'm pretty new to Lua so may be doing something completely stupid, but I've pored through my array several times looking for a misplaced character or extra { and I can't find one. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I get this error only if I leave out the comma after lots, i.e.: local array = {lots of, array, elements} Can you check your original source to see if you left out a comma?

Comment: You're looking for the wrong thing, more than likely you're missing a `,` somewhere. Do a text search for 'OF'.

Comment: Show a piece of exact code that could reproduce the error.

Comment: @greatwolf Thank you! I can't believe I was too stupid to do a simple search for 'OF' - it was late last night, I'll conveniently blame it on that. Instead of poring over my huge array time after time and finding nothing, if I'd done a text search from the start I'd have quickly seen that about half way through my array there was a single underscore missing. Problem solved, thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

There's no problems with this snippet, see confirmation: http://ideone.com/d7v49D

```
local array = {lots,
               of,
               array,
               elements}
```

Here we have new array construction, consisting of 4 global variable's values. Nothing special, no reserved keywords, etc.